Maximum of exponentially-tailed variables
Suppose that $X$ is a random variable on supported $\mathbb{R}$ and denote $f_X$ its density. Assume also that $f_X$ has "exponential tailed", i.e.:
$$f_X(x)\sim_{x\to+\infty} Ze^{-ax}$$
where $Z,a>0$. If we consider $n$ independent variables with the density $f_X$, can we say something on the behaviour of $Y_n:=\max_{1\leq i \leq n} X_i$ (in probability for example) ?
My intuition is that we have $Y_n\sim\log n$ in probability (up to some multiplicative constant) but I was not able to derive something until now.
Do you have some references or solution for this topic ?
Thank you very much!

You should look into extreme-value theory

https://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/A18n315.pdf

We do have $Y_n\sim x_n:=\frac1a\,\ln n$ in probability as $n\to\infty$.
Indeed, $G(x):=P(X>x)=(c+o(1))e^{-ax}$ as $x\to\infty$, where $c:=Z/a$. So,
for any real $p>0$,
$$P(Y_n>px_n)=1-(1-G(px_n))^n=1-(1-(c+o(1))n^{-p})^n
\to
\begin{cases}
0&\text{ if }p>1 \\ 
1&\text{ if }p<1 
\end{cases}$$
as $n\to\infty$.
So, $Y_n/x_n\to1$ in distribution and hence in probability.
$\quad\Box$

Thank you very much for this beautiful answer!
